# How to use UUID_GENERATE_V4() in PostgreSQL CSV import

Tags: excel, postgresql, csv, uuid

Am having a UUID field(With not null condition) in my table. I want to import data into that table.

How to use UUID_GENERATE_V4() in CSV file similar to using NOW()?

[Sample CSV Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaP8l.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, 'NOW()' is not a function call, it is just a string.  That the input conversion function for timestamps accepts the string 'NOW()' is a special case for that type, there is no analogous special case for uuid.

You might be able to alter the uuid input function (or define your own type) so that it would incorporate such a special case, but that is probably overkill.  The more conventional way would be to define the columns to have a default of UUID_GENERATE_V4(), and then to omit the columns from the COPY command (using the `tablename (col_list)` syntax) and also omit from the csv file.

Comment: Usually I'll be doing this by setting default value for the column. Just I was wondering is there any possibility of doing it in CSV. Thanks @jjanes